# Why can't I annotate a function expression as void despite that it returns nothing in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function expression that returns nothing. However, the following doesn't work.

```
let printHello: void = (): void => console.log('Hello!');
```

However, if I change the type to `object` it works!

```
let printHello: object = () => console.log('Hello!');
```

I think I have the actual function under control. However, I can't seem to annotate the variable `printHello` correctly...

Comment: Because *the function itself* isn't void, it's a *function*. `let printHello: () => void = () => console.log('Hello!');` would work, for example.

Comment: What do you mean *"without the fat arrow"*? Which one? It's *necessary* for the function type, `() => void`, although the other part could be a regular function `function() { console.log('Hello!'); }`.

Comment: Aaah okay... I think I just got it. So basically what `let printHello: () => void` says is that the variable `printHello` will have the type `() => void`... Followed by the actual function definition. Is that correct?

Comment: It's always the same: `let <name>: <type> = <value>;`. Your *type* is `void`, but the *value* is a function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So is this standard practice? Or do you think it's better to just do `let printHello = () => console.log('Hello!');`?

Comment: That would infer the correct type of `() => void`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the wonderful explanation. Now, I just need to know which is better to do. `let printHello: () => void = () => console.log('Hello!');` or `let printHello = () => console.log('Hello!');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TS variable declaration always takes the same form:

```
let <name>[: <type>][ = <value>];
```

In your case:

```
let printHello: void = (): void => console.log('Hello!');
//     name   | type | value
```

*(The function also has the `: void` return type, but that's part of the value so not relevant here.)*

However, the actual type of the value, which can be inferred if we remove the explicit type from the declaration:

```
let printHello = (): void => console.log('Hello!');
```

is **not** `void`, it's `() => void` - the value itself isn't undefined, it's a function *returning* undefined. So if you do want to explicitly include the type and not rely on inference (which [*"may add unnecessary verbosity"*](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-inferrable-types.md)), it would have to be:

```
let printHello: () => void = (): void => console.log('Hello!');
//     name   |    type    |    value
```

`object` works not because your function returns an object (it doesn't), but because a function *is* an object.